# Angular UI-router - keep url param across more states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to build an application similar to Google Analytics using UI-router. On the first page there are many website profiles and when I choose one profile, its id is then kept in url no matter on which GA page I am (Reporting, Customization, Admin).

I can't figure out how this can be done with UI-router. The most simple answer could be to put profile id into each state url and also to every link in partial views. This would be hard to maintain.

I want to keep profile id in url for 2 reasons:

- to enable bookmarking and page refresh
- to allow user to work with different profiles in different browser tabs

What's the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

– define state like this

```
.state('yourState', {
    url: 'state/:paramOne/:paramTwo',
    templateUrl: 'yourstate.html',
    controller: 'YourStateCtrl'
})
```

– make $stateParams accessible across your views

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
});
```

– apply current $stateParams values to links in views;  if not defined yet - use default values (might be `$rootScope.defaultParamOne = ''; $rootScope.defaultParamTwo = '';` )

```
<a ui-sref="yourState({
    paramOne: $stateParams.paramOne || defaultParamOne, 
    paramTwo: $stateParams.paramTwo || defaultParamTwo
})">your state</a>
```

This way ui-router will take params from current url and use it to build links.

Comment: Thank you, it works nicely. I already had $stateParams accessible on $rootScope but did not realize that I can use this variable in ui-sref to build a link.

Comment: You're welcome. You can also use it as $scope.$stateParams in your controllers without injecting $rootScope into them, btw. It's like global variables, so it's better not to mess it too much.